# Regex to allow only two words, one space and limit to 50 characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression with the following conditions:

- Only two words
- allow one space after the last word
- Maximum length 50

like ("firstname lastname ")

Thanks.

Comment: To enforce the length, use a look-ahead such as `(?=.{,50})`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a regex which covers all your requirements, including the length check:

```
^(?!.{51,})(\w+\s+\w+ ?)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^(?!.{51,})    assert that the string is not followed by 51 or more characters
(
    \w+        match a word
    \s+        followed by one or more spaces
    \w+        followed by a second word
     ?         ending with an optional space
)$
```

```js
function tests(str){
  var regex = /^(?!.{51,})(\w+\s+\w+ ?)$/;
  if (regex.test(str)) {
      console.log("passes");
  }
  else {
      console.log("fails");
  }
}
tests("firstname lastname ");  // passes
tests("first name last name"); // fails
tests("123456789 1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"); // passes (length 50)
tests("123456789 12345678901234567890123456789012345678901"); // fails (length 51)
```

## Regex 101

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const validate = data =>  /^\w+\s*\w+ ?$/.test(data) && data.length <= 50

const testData = ['this works', 'this    too ', '  this fails', 'firstname lastname ', ' firstname middlename lastname ']

for (let temp of testData) {
    console.log(`${temp} ${validate(temp)}`)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function tests(str){
  var pat=/^[a-zA-Z]+\s[a-zA-Z]+\s?$/;
  if(pat.test(str) && str.length<=50){
    console.log("true");
  }
  else{
    console.log("false");
  }
}
tests("firstname lastname "); //true
tests("first name last name"); //flase
```

Comment: how to allow the second word optional?

Comment: @Miranda group the second part and put `?` to indicate 0 or 1 occurance. If you want more than 1, use `*`. Here's the regex `/^[a-zA-Z]+(\s[a-zA-Z]+)?$/`

Answer (score 0):

You can check word count by splitting string into array like this

```
var array = "some string".split(" "); //result - ["some","string"]
```

Now you can check word count

```
var count = array.length; //will return 2
```

You can count letters like this

```
var letterCount = "some string".length; //will return 11
```

Way easier and better than using regex.

Answer (score 0):

This pattern will help `/^[a-Z]+\s[a-Z]+\s?$/`

```
<input type="text" pattern="^[a-Z]+\s[a-Z]+\s?$" title="Must be two words...">
```